# How to properly type an Object.assign-like generic function?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to create an "assign default" function in TypeScript, where it loops through the keys of the `source`, and if that value by the same key is nullish in the `target`, it will use the value from the `source` instead. Here's my attempt:

```js
const assignDefault = <T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U => {
  Object.keys(source).forEach(key => {
    // typecasted as Object.keys returns string[]
    const prop = target[key as keyof T]
    if (typeof prop === 'undefined' || prop === null) {
      // Error: Type 'U[keyof U]' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.
      target[key as keyof T] = source[key as keyof U] 
    }
  })
  return target // Error: Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T & U'.
}
```

I borrowed the generics from how `Object.assign` is typed in TypeScript:

```js
ObjectConstructor.assign<T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U;
```

But I couldn't find a way to get around these errors.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhCBLA5mAIgUwGZwK4A2sAvDADwAqANDAKoB8AFFHAE4qZQBcM1MEIPK2CYetAJQ8KMAGR0YxejADeAKBgwA8gCMAVpmBQAdAGtMATwiMBQkeKPYQrAKJxgAC0ZnzCpWo0aAPSBMFDmAA4GCFCYACbwEFp6BsbeiaycQpD8UKxIYCgA2gC66gGgkLDhrCDhCqFsHFCF3gkw3iDYvKUBMEhdzBGYnTDVtQrEpADkeGCxOPlxUzAAPiujNXWTpGCEBOIqZb3BMM6sNaxSQzBTtC0WI7TFy0iJYCCwCMhocNoEmKEQKFrlMKPdzCMKM8jEcAix2JxwW0Ol0ofUbMJMEiEO0Hl0njBYQBfMpE8RlDJQLINBGwE5nC5XSI3CgvN4fBLfMC-f6A4HM0GyOhTGFEoA)

Comment: I think the function type that correctly reflects your intent should rather be `<T, U = Partial<T>>(target: T, source: U): T` since you do not want to add any new properties not already part of `T`? See the [`Partial` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#partialtype)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.

Couple things to note:

`typeof` will never return `"null"` see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof

second thing the type `T & U` expects a combination of both the target and source. You can achieve that fairly easily by using the spread operator to merge them as shown in my example.

[EDIT] Instead of being restricted by the type you required. I completed modified the function to fit more with your original intention.

```typescript
const assignDefault = (target: Record<string, unknown>, source: Record<string, unknown>): Record<string, unknown> => {
    for (const key in source) {
        if (target[key] === null || typeof target[key] === 'undefined') {
            target[key] = source[key];
        }
    }
    return target;
}

const myTarget = {
    prop1: null,
    prop2: "some value",
    prop3: ["some", "other", "value"]
}

const mySource = {
    prop1: "hello world",
    prop2: "don't show this value",
    prop3: [],
    prop4: "a value not provided by target originally"
}

// expect
/**
 * {
 *  prop1: "hello world",
 *  prop2: "some value",
 *  prop3: ["some", "other", "value"],
 *  prop4: "a value not provided by target originally"
 * }
 */

const newObj = assignDefault(myTarget, mySource);

console.log(newObj);
```

Note that this function only really works with objects with key value pairs.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work according to my compiler, it is the same issue where `Type 'T[keyof T] | U[keyof U]' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.` Also the spread operators alone wouldn't do it as a shorthand as it would overwrite non-nullish values.

Comment: I think there might be some confusion. In this example the values of `target` would not be over-written. I've made a little pastebin that demonstrates the spread shorthand a little better. [playground](https://shorturl.at/uBCN1)

Comment: of course a value of `null` would not be over-written. If you want an example that over-writes null values and undefined values by defaults (like your original question seems to intended) let me know and I can update my answer.

Comment: I decided to update my answer with something that just solves your problem and ignores the types  you desired.

Answer (score 0):

> I borrowed the generics from how Object.assign is typed

There is a big difference between type definitions and implementation. The compiler is happy with the `: T & U` from the standard library because there is no conflicting information. In your implementation, however, the type of `target` is just `T`, whereas the signature expects `T & U`, hence the compiler error.

The compiler is not a runtime, so although it does some control flow analysis, it cannot infer that `forEach` mutates `target`. There are ways of making the compiler aware of that, though. The simplest one is [asserting the type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) of the `return`ed value either as `any` (to disable the type checker for it) or `T & U`:

```js
const assignDefault = <T, U>(target: T, source: U): T & U => {
    Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
        const prop = target[key as keyof T]
        if (typeof prop === 'undefined' || prop === null) {
          // Error: Type 'U[keyof U]' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.
          target[key as keyof T] = source[key as keyof U] 
        }
    });
    return target as T & U;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhhCBLA5mAIgUwGZwK4A2sAvDADwAqANDAKoB8AFFHAE4qZQBcM1MEIPK2CYetAJQ8KMAGR0YxejADeAKBgwA8gCMAVpmBQAdAGtMATwiMBQkeKPYQrAKJxgAC0ZnzCpWo0aAPSBMFDmAA4GCFCYACbwEFp6BsbeiaycQpD8UKxIYCgA2gC66gGgkLDhrCDhCqFsHFCF3gkw3iDYvKUBMEhdzBGYnTDVtQrEpADkeGCxOPlxUzAAPiujNXWTpGCEBOIqZb3BMM6sNaxSQzBTtC0WI7TFy0iJYCCwCMhocNoEmKEQKFrlMKPdzCMKM8jEcAix2JxwW0Ol0ofUbMJMEiEO0Hl0njBYQBfMpE8RlDJQLINBGfRLSOS0ADcqiJTKAA)

However, there is another issue with the return type of `assignDefault`: `T & U` is an intersection, which is not what you want. To properly type "if nullish, assign", one needs a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with some [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and `extends` checks to determine if a property can be assigned.

Such a type could look something like this:

```js
type AssignIfNullish<T, U> = {
    [P in keyof T]:  
        T[P] extends null | undefined ? // is value a subtype of null|undefined?
        U[P & keyof U]: // take the value from U
        T[P] // preserve the original
};

// type Test = { a: "null"; b: "undefined"; c: 42; }
type Test = AssignIfNullish<
    { a: null,  b: undefined,  c: 42 }, 
    { a:"null", b:"undefined", c: 24 }
>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=3&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznAlgcwHYEkBmA5ArgG30TgAsAeAFQBooBVAPigF4oBvAKCi6gG0AFKIlRQA1hBAB7TFAoBdAFxdO3FRX6yoEAB7AIqACZwoqAvigAfKLgMRMQiPqgB%20KMpVda-KADJR4qXQKru7canwa7AC%20ANzs7AD08VCgkDIQcMDMbFAAhooARCaE%20dFQAEYF1vq29volUADGigAsAEylkewp0BTpmSzwSGhYeITE5G7ZeUX4VBVVNagOVE1QbVCRNJOsufKFpvk0FfkLdkt1NKutzRvs9NFAA)

The rest is just a matter of asserting the return type of the function:

```js
const assignDefault = <T, U>(target: T, source: U) => {
    Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
        const prop = target[key as keyof T]
        if (typeof prop === 'undefined' || prop === null) {
          // Error: Type 'U[keyof U]' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.
          target[key as keyof T] = source[key as keyof U] 
        }
    });
    return target as AssignIfNullish<T, U>;
};

assignDefault({ a:1,b:null } as const,{ b:42 } as const); // { a:1, b:42 }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznAlgcwHYEkBmA5ArgG30TgAsAeAFQBooBVAPigF4oBvAKCi6gG0AFKIlRQA1hBAB7TFAoBdAFxdO3FRX6yoEAB7AIqACZwoqAvigAfKLgMRMQiPqgB%20KMpVda-KADJR4qXQKru7canwa7AC%20ANzs7ADGEqhwwFAAhggoqAAitmkEqSyUNAwAFMBpAE7IEMCK1FBwEriV8RCKtACUzIwcKgDyAEYAVhDxwAB0YiBwpU0tbZ0TmBKVAKJp8SSlpdPdTL1u7onJqWCVEmDMUBXVtTzT6UbTAXJHKojS5eAQAeeXzCYLAA5NZ9LZ7PpgRZLP8rkCWCZCN0%20iFuAB6dFQNaVC6Veo-KDAzwvaS0WTQ4jGCSpDJINBpQb4aDACQ3QnAtSkmQUibvdy3GrAB7iJ5%20STSOTXeatCAikBi7nk4JoyJHSKdWIqSq1FrCQW1MXwekYHCmYjkBoMWIxOJ0rK5TD5fDAUqsdLyACMVEG8iRZkiYpOKSo7t9ABYAExQQMZKDB4CaqCYtge71QCPRyJAA)

Finally, there is one more error to deal with:

> Error: Type 'U[keyof U]' is not assignable to type 'T[keyof T]'.

The compiler checks if `U[keyof U]` (`source[key]`) is assignable to `T[keyof T]` (`target[key]`), but it does not have any information on how `T` and `U` are related. All it knows is that both are generic type parameters and thus can be anything. According to the signature, it is not even guaranteed that either is an object (*you* know that but not the compiler):

```js
assignDefault(true, false); // no objection from the compiler
```

Since in this instance you know more than the compiler, it is ok to use `as unknown as T[keyof T]` to assert that `source[key]` is actually `T[keyof T]`:

```js
const assignDefault = <
    T extends object,
    U extends object
>(target: T, source: U) => {
    Object.keys(source).forEach((key) => {
        const prop = target[key as keyof T]
        if (typeof prop === 'undefined' || prop === null) {
            target[key as keyof T] = source[key as keyof U] as unknown as T[keyof T];
        }
    });
    return target as AssignIfNullish<T, U>;
};

assignDefault(true, false); // error as expected
assignDefault({ a:null }, { a:42, b: "extra" }); // ok, { a:number }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznAlgcwHYEkBmA5ArgG30TgAsAeAFQBooBVAPigF4oBvAKCi6gG0AFKIlRQA1hBAB7TFAoBdAFyduFfrKgQAHsAioAJnCioC%20KAB8ouPRExCIuqAH4lXWvygAyUeKl01i7jKq7AC%20ANzs7ADGEqhwwFAAhggoqAAi1gkE8SxkzjLqWjr6UBIARgBWEJHAVHm0Bdp6BmWV1ez0ABTACQBOyBDA8jI0cBK4PZEQQ7QAlMyMHAEA8hVVwAB0YiBwHaPjkzPrmBI9AKIJkSQdHVtzTAt5AdGx8WA9EmDMUN19AzxbiQMWx8cke3EQ0i64AgPjeH2YTBYAHJLLprLZdEizOY4Z9ESwjIQ5osAqSuD9%20sB-uJAV5JNI5F89hMINSQLTgdJaGokhZUCJUBIAO7CXkqTkyWThMlcYJ5YIzaXcHoDcbCCkDWnwJBoLB4QjEcjUOj0cJhCJJHVpDJZLo9XAQGiYBL4OAQRVQAD0nvUPXePVpmkg1Ts7EtKXSzttrES8kJJmCNBjCXkABYAEw0UpDABEmmAPQSOagCtCXp9EhESdjRgAtqUIAHgkA)

That is a lot of assertions, though, can we do better? Yes, if we forgo the `Object.keys` in favor of the good old `for...in` loop because of the quirk that `key` is typed as `string` (there is a good reason for it, but still). Using `for...in` (with the appropriate guard) allows us to drop the `as keyof` assertions:

```js
const assignDefault = <
    T extends Partial<{ [P in keyof U]: unknown }> & object,
    U extends Partial<{ [P in keyof T]: unknown }> & object
>(target: T, source: U) => {
    for (const key in source) {
        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(source, key)) continue;

        const prop = target[key];

        if (typeof prop === 'undefined' || prop === null) {
            Object.assign(target, key, { [key]: source[key] });
        }
    }

    return target as AssignIfNullish<T, U>;
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=3&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggznAlgcwHYEkBmA5ArgG30TgAsAeAFQBooBVAPigF4oBvAKCi6gG0AFKIlRQA1hBAB7TFAoBdAFyduFfrKgQAHsAioAJnCioC%20KAB8ouPRExCIuqAH4lXWvygAyUeKl01i7jKq7AC%20ANzs7ADGEqhwwFAAhggoqAAi1gkE8SxkzjLqWjr6UHwJAE7AiAn4ZKy8AkJektK0ChaoIqgSAO7CwYyeEgBGAFYQkcBUebQF2noGpRVVNXVujWLNMm2WnT19A1DDYxPs9AAUwOXIEMDyMjRwErhlkRB3tACUzIwceZgSZSgZ2isXiG0Ewkez1eXw4AQCiGkZwAhAB5UbjYAAOjAZQkwHx4AgWJISVRvT4eMgFRAWMi1XwZyhLwgNA2Hy%20IMqRgg4TyARBcSguIkYGYUEuZWuwB4G1kfPh3ERQNAkB8IrFTC1UAA5JZdNZbLodWZzBrmNqjIRYfzFVB0cdsUkkGgLlcbmzxDRVnK7szXrLxGpgh9wnaoME8pG8mUbs9hJLpYkDPAXRgcMZiORqHR6OEwhFnSl0phMvhgBcyrhWVBS-g4BBQ1AAPTN9RlPGApIFSATOzsItoEtlit1BJ3K0mYLexJ3AAsACYaEM7gAiTTAMoJVcRputw4iGfjowAWyGEEBwSAA)

Notice the use of `Object.assign(target, key, { [key]: source[key] });` to avoid the assignability error (one could also use `Object.defineProperty(target, key, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(source, key)!);`).